# How to pass a Array list or a dataset to R and get the result back to Java

Tags: java, r

I would like to send a dataset (Array list, DataFrames) from Java to R. And Get the result back as Array list or data frame

Comment: How about an example of your data

Answer (score 0):

How about [JRI](https://www.rforge.net/JRI/) or [rJava](https://www.rforge.net/rJava/)? The first one allows you to run R from within Java and the latter one allows you the opposite to run Java from within R. I'm sure there are possibilities to exchange data.